# Python Asyncio is not running new coroutine using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe

Tags: python, python-asyncio

1>Python Asyncio is not running new coroutine using asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe. Below is the code testing performed on Mac.
————————————————————————————————

```
import os    
import random      
import asyncio      
import logging     
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor      
     
os.environ['PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG'] = '1'      
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)      
    
async def coro():      
    print("Coroutine {} is has started")      
    
      
async def main(loop):     
    print(" 1 ")    
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro(), loop)      
    print(f"Future  --")          
    print(" 2 ")      
    print(" Result ",fut.result())      
    print(" 3 ")      
    
if __name__== '__main__':      
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()      
    loop.set_debug(True)      
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

————————————————————————————————
Output:

```
 1       
Future -- <Future at 0x102a05358 state=pending>      
 2
```

=============================================================================

2>The output is same when I run on a different executor also as shown below
—————————————————————————————————————

```
new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()      
new_loop.set_default_executor(ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2))      
fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro(), new_loop)
```

—————————————————————————————————————
Sample code:

```
import os      
import random      
import asyncio      
import logging      
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor      
      
os.environ['PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG'] = '1'      
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)      
      
async def coro():      
    print("Coroutine {} is has started")      
      
      
async def main(loop):    
    print(" 1 ")    
    new_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()    
    new_loop.set_default_executor(ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2))    
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro(), new_loop)      
    print(f"Future  --")        
    print(" 2 ")      
    print(" Result ",fut.result())      
    print(" 3 ")      
    
if __name__== '__main__':      
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()    
    loop.set_debug(True)      
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

————————————————————————————————
Output:

```
 1
Future  -- <Future at 0x102f5d668 state=pending>    
 2
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe):

> This function is meant to be called from a different OS thread than the one where the event loop is running

```
async def coro():
    print("Coroutine {} is has started")

def start_coro(loop):
    fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro(), loop)
    print(fut.result())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)
    Thread(target=start_coro, args=(loop,)).start()
    loop.run_forever()
```

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet submits a coroutine to the event loop it is already running in. You don't need `run_coroutine_threadsafe` for that, you can just call `asyncio.create_task`. As mentioned in the other answer, the idea with `run_coroutine_threadsafe` is that you run it from your **sync** code in order to submit a task to an event loop running in another thread.

The other problem is that you never give a chance to the task to execute, as you don't await anything in `main()` and use `run_until_complete(main())` at top-level. As a result, the code only runs the event loop until `main()` completes, not caring for the tasks it might have spawned in the background. To fix it, you should either await the spawned task or return it so it can be awaited from top-level.

The second snippet submits a coroutine to a freshly created event loop that no one is running, so again the coroutine doesn't get a chance to execute. To fix it, you should execute `new_loop.run_forever` in an separate thread.

Finally, the executor as set by `set_default_executor` doesn't serve to execute coroutines. In asyncio (and other Python async frameworks) coroutines all run in a single thread, the one that runs the event loop. The execute concurrently through the virtue of `await` transferring control back to the event loop. The executor you've set serves to execute **blocking** code passed to [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).